# In QGIS Georeferencer: Mysterious OGR Driver Error: not found OGR

Tags: qgis, ogr, georeferencing

I have been georeferencing Vector files (gpkg and shp) in the new Georeferencer in QGIS 3.30.1. The files are pretty large, have multiple million features and a size of roughly 2-3gb.

I have successfully georeferenced 2 of those files with no issues in the georeferencer, but when attempting to georef 2 additional files (which have been created through the exact same process and model) I got this error:

```
OGR Driver error: not found (OGR:
```

I have tried a lot of things, including:

Trying different georef algorithms, repairing the geometries, trying to georef them as shapefiles, running QGIS on a different machine, completely reinstalling and installing the newest version of QGIS

but to no avail.

I still cannot georeference them. This is especially puzzling since with the other two files (created equally and of actually bigger size) i had 0 problems.

Do you have any insight on where this error comes from, if it is related to the files themselves or rather the nature of QGIS and OGR?

Comment: Shapefiles won't work if they are bigger than 2Gb and are pretty unreliable at 1Gb even.

Comment: A vector geopackage i georeferenced earlier was 3.3gb of size and it worked well. With around 50 GCP and on Polynominal 3 i got accuracy up to 2-5m which is enough for my usecase. So i suspect it cannot be the size that is causing the error as the files that fail have a size of only about 1.5gb

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution! It is a weird one but hear me out.

This issue is related to the FILENAME you give your georeferenced image.

The files i wanted to georeferenced were named: *final_geopackage_9_12_13.gpkg*

When georeferencing QGIS automatically changes this into *final_geopackage_9_12_13_modified.gpkg*

When i tried to save a the file under this name i got the OGR Driver error. However under a different name it worked.

But it gets weirder. Simply changing parts of the filename dont work either. For example when changing the name from *final_geopackage_9_12_13_modified.gpkg*
to *final_geopackage_9_12_13_georeferenced.gpkg* or maybe *final_geopackage_9_12_13_Lets_hope_it_works_this_time.gpkg* **WILL NOT WORK.**

Dont ask me how or why but OGR seems to get tripped up over any resembelance to the original filename.

Renaming the file to e.g *Peter.gpkg* or *ABCD.gpkg* made the error disappear and the georeferencing work flawlessly.

Comment: Fantastic, I came across the same issue as well and this fixed it, thank you! In my case it was because there was a full stop (.) in the filename before the actual extension - removed just that and the rest of it worked. Maybe it depends on what OS you are using too in terms of filename compliance.